# Generate private and public key file using keytool

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, keytool

I want to know if there is a way to create .key file for (public and private key) using keytool , I understand that we can generate a keystore using below command

`keytool -genkeypair -keysize 2048 -keyalg RSA -alias appalias -keystore D:\..\..`

which has the keypair , I am also aware of java way of retrieving the keys from keystore , but is there a direct way for it using KEYTOOL

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to extract the public keys using keytool, check this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jsse/j-jsse.html).

> Export/import commands We'll use the *keytool -export* command to
>   extract the public key into a file, and then use the *keytool -import*
>   command to insert it into a new keystore. Here's the command to
>   extract the client's public key:
>
> ```
> keytool -export -alias clientprivate -keystore client.private -file temp.key -storepass clientpw
> ```
>
> And here's the command to insert the client's private key into its own keystore:
>
> ```
> keytool -import -noprompt -alias clientpublic -keystore client.public -file temp.key -storepass public
> ```
>
> We'll also extract and store the server's public key. Here's the command to extract the key:
>
> ```
> keytool -export -alias serverprivate -keystore server.private -file temp.key -storepass serverpw
> ```
>
> And here's the command to place it in its own keystore:
>
> ```
> keytool -import -noprompt -alias serverpublic -keystore server.public -file temp.key -storepass public
> ```

Comment: This is misleading. Your examples don't extract a "public" key or a "private" key in the strict sense of encryption. They simply extract the key identified by the alias. Indeed the two -export and -import commands are identical except for the file names and aliases.

Answer (score 1):

As per the findings there is no direct way to extract the private key out of the keystore , this link [How can I export my private key from a Java Keytool keystore?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore) helped to me extract the keys , it requires OpenSSL but i think thats the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember puttygen can generate public and private key files. Try it and let me know if it works.
Regards

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: Thanks for replying NevyanovL , puttygen can be a way to generate keys and we also have openssl that can do the job but its like i am looking for a way where it can be done using keytool only